# Check if user exists in database table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to write a method if to check if the user has added an object to their bookmarks however, I am struggling on how to write it so I can pass it into my template.

So I have two types of **models** for bookmarking different objects:

```
class BookmarkBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class BookmarkPost(BookmarkBase):
    class Meta:
        db_table  = "bookmark_post"
    
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    obj = models.ForeignKey('home.Post',on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Post")

class BookmarkBlog(BookmarkBase):
    class Meta:
        db_table  = "bookmark_blog"
        
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    obj = models.ForeignKey('home.Blog',on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Blog")
```

And my **view** and **URLs** that are responsible for handling adding/removing Objects to bookmarks are:

```
@login_required
def add_bookmark(request, id, obj_type):
    data=dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if obj_type=='post':
            model = BookmarkPost
        elif obj_type=='blog':
            model = BookmarkBlog
        elif obj_type=='buzz':
            model = BookmarkBuzz
        user = auth.get_user(request)
        bookmark, created = model.objects.get_or_create(user=user, obj_id=id).remove()
        if not created:
            bookmark.delete()
        context = {'bookmark':bookmark}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('main/bookmark/bookmark.html',context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And urls is:

```
path('bookmark/<int:id>/<str:obj_type>/', views.add_bookmark,name='add-bookmark'),
```

I am struggling on this part on how I can add this functionality so that if user has already added the bookmark it will change it icons and display the `{% else %}` part:

```
<form class="add-bookmark-form" method="POST">
    {% if request.user has not added object to bookmark %}
    <button class="small dropdown-item" type="submit" data-url="{% url 'main:add-bookmark' id=get_id obj_type=t %}" ><svg class="bi  mr-1 bi-bookmark" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 12l5 3V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12l5-3zm-4 1.234l4-2.4 4 2.4V3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v10.234z"/>
      </svg></i>Bookmark</button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="small dropdown-item" type="submit" data-url="{% url 'main:add-bookmark' hid=get_hash obj_type=t %}" ><svg class="bi mr-1 bi-bookmark-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12l-5-3-5 3V3z"/>
      </svg></i>Bookmarked</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do that by creating another route which will be called when somebody bookmarks something and add that "else" functionality there.